# htaccess redirect to subdirectory to root 2 folders

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I want to redirect my sub directory to root.

Here is my code

http://exmple.com/ar/index.php

And want to redirect like

http://exmple.com/index.php?language_id=2

please suggest something,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ar/index.php$ /index.php?lang_id=2 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Your code is work but how to include    http://localhost/bilal-bhatti/al_maarif_final/ar/index.php

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.